# Filter with custom condition in mongo DB query not working

Tags: c#, mongodb-query

I have a collection with date time field. I want to filter the data with id and datetime field. Need to check the difference in milliseconds. But getting following error

Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to determine the serialization information for s => (DateTime.UtcNow - s.BilledDateTime.Value).TotalMilliseconds.
at MongoDB.Driver.Linq.Linq2Implementation.LinqProviderAdapterV2.TranslateExpressionToField[TDocument,TField](Expression`1 expression, IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry
serializerRegistry, Boolean allowScalarValueForArrayField)
at MongoDB.Driver.ExpressionFieldDefinition`2.Render(IBsonSerializer`1 documentSerializer, IBsonSerializerRegistry serializerRegistry, LinqProvider linqProvider, Boolean allowScalarValueForArrayFie
ld)

```
 var builder = Builders<T>.Filter;
            var filter = builder.Where(t =>
                t.Status == 1
            );
            filter &= builder.Gte(s => (DateTime.UtcNow - s.BilledDateTime.Value).TotalMilliseconds, 10000);
            return await Collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current filter you have is effectively a request to the Mongo driver to compute the value of `now - BilledDateTime` for each document and then see if the result is >= 10000 milliseconds. The C# driver does not support this kind of query in this way, and it isn't a smart idea to evaluate each document one by one as part of a filter.

This is rather trivial to turn on its head though. Your goal here is to find billed dates that are more than 10000 milliseconds ago. A simple solution then is to precompute the date and time value that was 10000 milliseconds ago:

```
var threshold = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMilliseconds(-10000);
```

We can then use this in the query, and the database can use an index if the property is indexed, resulting in a more efficient query:

```cs
filter &= builder.Lt(s => s.BilledDateTime.Value, threshold);
```